# how to unerstand finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> A vector space $V$ is called **finite-dimensional** if there is a finite subset of $V$ that is a basis for $V$. If there is no such finite subset of $V$, then $V$ is called **infinite-dimensional**.
>
> ---
>
> We now establish some results about finite-dimensional vector spaces that will tell about the number of vectors in a basis, compare two different bases, and give properties of bases. First, we observe that if $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf v_2,\dotsc, \mathbf v_k\}$ is a basis for a vector space $V$, then $\{c\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2, \dotsc, \mathbf v_k\}$ is also a basis when $c\neq 0$ (Exercise 35). Thus a basis for a nonzero vector space is never unique.
>   [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghEh9.png)

I am confused if $\mathbb R^2$ is a finite dimensional vector space. $[1 \ 0],[0 \  1]$ will be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$. However, there are also $[2 \ 0],[0 \ 1]$ and I can find infinite many to be the basis of $\mathbb R^2$. So, $\mathbb R^2$ is an infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: No, the dimension is the number of linearly independent elements of a basis. In all your examples this number is $2$. There are an infinite number of bases, but each basis has exactly $2$ elements.

Comment: You understand the world is 3-dimensional because there are at most 3 independent directions you can point in at a time. This is not changed by the fact there are infinitely many choices of 3 independent directions to point in.

Comment: Oh, so R2 is finite dimensional vector space since the number of elements can only be 2. Thank you, but why in the picture I post, it says "there is a finite subset of V that is a basis for V", which is very confusing.

Comment: It seems you're confusing "there is a finite basis" with "there are only finitely many bases."  The former refers to the number of vectors in a (particular) basis; the latter refers to the number of bases.  In $\mathbb R^2$, the former is true and the latter is false.

Comment: The definition says "there is a finite subset of $V$ that is a basis for $V$." All we care about is existence of one such finite subset. The vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are indeed a finite subset of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  And they are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So $\mathbb{R}^2$ is finite dimensional, according to that correct definition. There might be many other finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that also form a basis, we do not care.  We just have to find one such subset and that proves finite dimensional.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I got it now, and thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are mixing the terms "finite subset" and "finite number of subset".

The first one corresponds to the fact that in the subset there are only finitely many ${\it elements}$; the second one corresponds to the fact that there are finitely many ${\it subsets}$.

Hope I helped. I also mixed these two concepts at the start of learning linear algebra, so I think you met the same problem.

Comment: God, thank you! This is exactly what confused me...

Comment: @ikd29123 Yeah. Sometimes you get confused if you automatically thought it was that way. I am happy that I helped.

Comment: If my problem is solved, what I should do? Just leave it there?@Junkai Dong

Comment: @ikd29123 I think you can try marking upvotes for several useful answers  and marking one answer that solves your problem as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why this question was downvoted since it is an honest one. For a vector space $V$, the existence of a finite basis is all you need to determine the dimension (which is unique). This is because you can show that if $A$ is a basis for $V$ and $|A| = n$ then any other basis $B$ for $V$ also have to have cardinality $n$.

Comment: Thank you! According to the definition of my text book and the example of R2.{[1 0],[0 1]} is subset.{[2 0],[0 1]} is another one. I think I can find infinite subset. So, the definition is wrong?

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I think it is correct, but why my text book says like that?

Comment: @ikd29123 No, the definition is not wrong. You can find infinitely many bases for R2. But can you find *one single* basis which contains infinitely many vectors? (The answer is no, there is no such basis.)

Comment: No, they are not wrong. We do require that if $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis for $V$ then $v_i \in V$ i.e $\{v_1,...,v_n\} \subset V$. Otherwise if some $v_i =V$ then that doesn't make since because for a basis vector we have $v_i \in V$ but $V \not \in V$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n$, the following is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, ${\cal B}_n = \{ (0,1), (n,1) \}$.

So, each ${\cal B}_n$ has exactly two elements, but there is an infinite number of bases.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the point of "countable" here. I think there is even an uncountable number of $B_n$ in this case.

Comment: Of course there are, just take the standard basis and rotate by $\theta$. The point is that each basis has exactly $2$ elements, but there are an infinite number of bases.

Comment: Sure, but you said that "there are a countable number of bases". Well I suppose that was uncountable infinite, not countable infinite. I understand your point, but there is just a small confusion about the infinity you are referring to.

Comment: At the expense of rather awkward (and grammatically incorrect) wording, I have removed the countable.

Comment: That should avoid the ambiguity. Thank you.